# Something taking the screen space invisibly, HELP?

Tags: 22.04, 23.04

Here's the screencast, It can be seen that **in the upper right corner**, there's **something preventing doing anything in the position**, if try to close an application that's close button is in that space that can't be clickable, I need to get rid of it.

Its Ubuntu 23.04 (installed 2 days earlier)

Scheencast: https://youtu.be/C0U8lkY-k0k